# Como reemplazar los mensajes de error

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Acabo de agregarle un texto a mi correo en caso el usuario introduzca un correo invalido, pero al momento de que coloque cualquier carácter, me aparece un mensaje distinto al que he puesto en ingles. Quisiera saber como cambiar ese mensaje de error que tiene por defecto.

```
    [Display(Name = "Correo:")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese un e-mail válido")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Ingrese su email")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima 100 carácteres")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Longitud mínima 3 carácteres")]
    public string correo_Inter { get; set; }
```

**Imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como estas declarando la caja de texto en la pagina.

Comment: Brother, ¿y si agregas tu vista y el HTML que se genera?